# doubt between Past Continuous and Past Simple

Tags: past-tense, past-simple, past-continuous

In the book English Grammar In Use by Raymond Murphy they gave the example for Past Continuous - ´Today Helen is wearing a skirt. Yesterday she was wearing trousers´. Please explain to me why it isn´t Past Simple because the action is complete, it had finished.

Comment: Very simple: was wearing is the past of is wearing.

Answer (score 2):

Very simple: **was wearing** is the past of **is wearing.** Also, it means over a period of time in the past.

Of course, you can say: She wore trousers yesterday.

**I am studying today.**
**Yesterday, I was not studying. In fact, I didn't study at all yesterday. I simply haven't studied at all recently.**

Continuous forms are for what a person wants to say as an ongoing action. The speaker chooses what tense to use in these cases.

Answer (score 2):

The action *today* isn't finished yet and is expected to continue for the rest of the day.

Yesterday she was wearing trousers for the whole day, not just part of it.

Compare:

*Today Helen wears a skirt for the photoshoot. Yesterday she wore trousers.*

This is for a limited period of time (during the photoshoot) not all day.

However, I would be quite happy to say "Today Helen *is wearin*g a skirt. Yesterday she *wore* trousers." idiomatically.

Sometimes you have to learn rules first, and then you will learn later that rules are broken.

Comment: Today, Helen *is wearing* a skirt, not wears, usually.